# IE border on opacity change

Tags: jquery, animation, internet-explorer, border, opacity

when I want to animate a semi transperant image with jquery (e.g. a div with a background who has a shadow) every element who is semi transperant seems to have a black border arround it in IE (6 - 8)

an example of the code is:

```
$(".prevPage").animate({
        opacity: "1"
    },
    250);
    $(".nextPage").animate({
        opacity: "1"
    },
    250);
```

image of the issue: http://img245.imageshack.us/img245/435/41509350.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not find any answer on the internet for this. I just made 2 versions of the image, one semi transperant the other not transperant.

If anyone has another fix, feel free to share

Answer (score 0):

add `filter: none !important;` to `.nextPage` and `.prevPage` in your CSS